# Possible to limit Android app by device, not by OS version?

Tags: android

If I want a certain application to be available for certain devices only or for tablets only, is there any way to make limitations by device (like I can limit the min/max Android OS version)?

I say it is impossible. Do you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you are trying to limit the devices that can see the application in the Market but, like you, I do not think that is possible.  You can, however, limit it within the app using details from and [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class.  `Build.PRODUCT` looks like it would fit your needs - if the phone that has the app installed in not in a pre-set list of "products", tell the user that they have the wrong version and exit.

A similar idea for tablets is to check [the screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions) - if they are under a certain threshold, then display that same message.

Comment: I was referring to the Market limitation, but thanks for suggestions on screen and installed app limitations, although if I am a user of that app, I would not like to see that message. Somehow it's just not user friendly. Market limitation should be the proper way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, starting in june this year. Please take a look at this Google I/O session:

http://youtu.be/GxU8N21wfrM